# Responsive svg marker icons in googlemaps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, svg, google-maps-api-3

I have a map ([**example here**](https://jsfiddle.net/yorch/7hrxrL6f/11/)), with customized svg icon markers:

```
var icon = {
  path: "M-10,0a10,10 0 1,0 20,0a10,10 0 1,0 -20,0",
  fillColor: '#FF0000',
  fillOpacity: .6,
  anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
  strokeWeight: 0,
  scale: 1
}
```

If you zoom in the map you will realize icon is immutable size,

[image]
[image]

there is a way to resize it when zooming? (zoom in makes icon bigger and zoom out smaller)

- I've found how to make svg icons responsive, but this forces me to add the svg into an element and use css.
- If I have lots of markers in a map, I know I can [group them](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers), but this is not what I'm searching.

Comment: Have you tried using [google.maps.Circle](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#circles) objects instead?  They have a fixed physical size (radius in meters)

Comment: uhmm... @geocodezip that sounds interesting, I'll check, but.... this is a sample only, we will add more elaborated vectors icons like glass of beer shape if possible...

Comment: One option is to adjust the scale of the SVG icon with zoom, but that will have performance implications if you have lots of markers.

Answer (score 1):

From your initialize method you can call the setZoomChangedEvent method as given below. This is just for proof of concept. You will need to decide the scale that you want depending on the zoom level and change the value of the variable "scale" inside the if-else-if ladder. The method checks the zoom level every time the zoom is changed and the scale is calculated according to the zoom. As geocodezip has mentioned in the comments there could be an impact on performance if there are a lot of markers on the map.

```
function setZoomChangedEvent()
{
    var prevscale = 3;
    var scale = 0;
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {

        var zoom = map.getZoom();

        if(zoom < 3)
        {
            scale = 2;
        }
        else if(zoom < 5 )
        {
            scale = 3;
        }
        else if(zoom < 10)
        {
            scale = 4;
        }
        else if(zoom < 15)
        {
            scale = 5;
        }
        else if(zoom < 20)
        {
            scale = 6;
        }

        if(scale!=prevscale)
        {
            var len = markers.length;
            for(var j=0; j<len; j++)
            {
                var icon = markers[j].getIcon();
                if(icon.hasOwnProperty("scale"))
                {
                    icon.scale = scale;
                    markers[j].setIcon(icon);
                }   
            }
        }
        prevscale = scale;
    });
}
```